# Using adb shell command to test apps, how to make it continue even one of the test fails?

Tags: android, unit-testing, testing, command-line, adb

I am testing an Android app using command like:

```
adb shell am instrument -w -e class net.mandaria.test.TippyTipperTest,net.mandaria.test.TippyTipperTest2,net.mandaria.test.TippyTipperTest3 net.mandaria.test/android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner
```

However, when one of the tests fails, the entire test execution stops. For example, if the first test "net.mandaria.test.TippyTipperTest" fails, I got this output:

```
net.mandaria.test.TippyTipperTest:INSTRUMENTATION_RESULT: shortMsg=junit.framework.AssertionFailedError
INSTRUMENTATION_RESULT: longMsg=junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: shows enter
INSTRUMENTATION_CODE: 0
```

My question is:
how can I make it continue to run all the tests, even if the first one fails?

Answer (score 0):

If you use `AndroidJUnitRunner`:

```
$ adb shell am instrument -w -r   -e debug false -e class com.example.MyClass com.example.test/android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner
```

and if some tests fail the result is printed at the end

```
...
FAILURES!!!
Tests run: 4,  Failures: 2


INSTRUMENTATION_CODE: -1
```